# Influx DB as a source for MLS as a direct connection

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

Can we use InfluxDB as a data source for Azure ML Serv, in the form of a direct connection.  If not, what are the proposed alternatives to setup this connection?
(Put differently, Is it possible for M LServ to connect to an InfluxDB next to some API to fetch data from. Or do we have to put all data in a SQL database?)

Answer (score 0):

One alternative way is you can use the `sql.to` function to write a table to a SQL database, for example Postgre DB. Azure Machine Learning and datasets supports accessing data from Azure Database for PostgreSQL.  link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-access-data

Here is example code:
    import "sql"
    sql.to(
       driverName: "postgres",
       dataSourceName: "postgresql://user:password@localhost",
       table: "ExampleTable"
    )

Comment: sql.to function can support writing to Postgre db. Azure ML and Dataset also provide the ability to download or mount files of any format from Azure Database for PostgreSQL.

Comment: example code for write to Postgre db using Influxdb sql.to() function:

import "sql"

sql.to(
  driverName: "postgres",
  dataSourceName: "postgresql://user:password@localhost",
  table: "ExampleTable"
)